# Philosophy of non duality or oneness it's equivalent in west

Tags: dualism, individualism

In India there is a philosophy of non duality / oneness / enlightenment...

And people practice it...
Is there something similar in western philosophy ?

Also there is this idea that the individual the person is just a concept or an idea in the mind...

In reality everything springs from one source..

Any inputs on above...
Thanks

Comment: See [Monism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/monism/): "Existence monism holds that exactly one concrete object token exists (the One). "

Comment: And see [Ontological idealism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/idealism/): the idea that "something mental (the mind, spirit, reason, will) is the ultimate foundation of all reality, or even exhaustive of reality."

Comment: [Neo-platonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoplatonism) (Plotinus) and [panentheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panentheism) (Spinoza, romantic idealists, Transcendental Club) are probably the closest analogs. See also the umbrella [perennial philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perennial_philosophy) that mixes Oriental and Western traditions.

Comment: Not to quibble since you are only suggesting populist philosophy citations,  but Spinoza's system 'Deus sive Natura' is not a spirit or being existing outside of creation. It is an 'immanent cause' which is inseparable from Nature. Even human beings 'express' a portion of this immanence in their capacity to entertain 'ideas' which express an 'aspect of eternty' as referenced to the 'Infinite intellect'. Cheers,